# Discrete math recursive definition

Tags: math, recursion, definition

So we were working this problem in class and for f(2) I got the same answer but for f(3) I got something different from the professor.

```
Basis: f(0) = -1 and f(1) = 2
Recursion: f(n) = f(n-2) - f(n-1)

For f(3) I am getting 1
f(3-2) - f(3-1)
=f(1) - f(2)
=2 - f(2-2) - f(2-1)
=2 - -1 - 2
=2+1-2 = 1
```

But the answer he got was:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=2 - -1 - 2
```

This should be

```
= 2 - (-1-2) = 2 + 1 + 2 = 5
```

Comment: Ohh gotcha because f(2) is the whole f(2-2) - f(2-1). Thanks!